# Can I pass a parameter to Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, looker-studio

My situation is the following. I have a huge amount of analytics in Google Analytics and my PostgresSQL database and I want to embed this on my dashboard.

The Data in GA looks like the following:

{ category: 'Shop Metrics', action: 'Some button clicked', label: 'shopId=' }

What I want to do now is to show every shop-owner only the events that fit to his specific SHOP-ID on our dashboard.

Now, is it possible to pass in this SHOP-ID to filter the information on demand?

If not, can you recommend any other free solution?

Comment: You could use the [Analytics Reporting API V4][1]. 
Pulling the information that you need into a dataframe and mix this data with your PostgresSQL creating subsets of data for Datastudio, remember that the max size for each is ~70MB. Or you can use something like Apache superset and have no limitations.


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=custom_variables_or_columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered the question at this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleDataStudio/comments/ayqxmz/can_i_pass_a_parameter_to_google_data_studio/eian4ne).

---- Original Answer ----

Yes. Using a Community Connector this will be very easy.

1. [Create a Community Connector](https://g.co/codelabs/CommunityConnectors).
2. Maintain an Access control list of shop-owner email addresses v shopId in a PostgresSQL table.
3. In the connector getData code, [get the effective user's email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser).
4. From the email, get the shopId (#2).
5. [Use a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) to fetch data from Google Analytics and PostgresSQL while filtering for shopId.
6. Create a datasource and [enforce viewer's credentials](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6371135).
7. Use datasource in #6 to create a report.
8. Share this report with all shop-owners.

When shop-owners open the dashboard, they will only see the data for their relevant shopIds.

Comment: Hi @Minhaz Kazi This will only work if user is logged in to google. Any other way that we can pass an ID to show a report that will be filtered with that particular ID. I have will have hundreds of ID's.

Comment: Here's another guide I wrote for the use case when user is not logged into Google: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials